# How to put a marker of the image of a person from firebase on the map?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app and I cant figure out how to put a marker to the location of a person from my Firebase. I have tried this:

```
                        var ocherednyara: LatLng
                            if(document.data.getValue("online") as Boolean){
                                ocherednyara = LatLng((document.data.getValue("latitude") as Double), (document.data.getValue("longitude") as Double))
                                placeMarkerOnMap(ocherednyara)
                                //placeMarkerOnMap(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
                                //Log.d("TAG", "${document.data.getValue("online")} ${document.data.getValue("email")}")
                            }
```

And calling this function in setUpMap():

```
private fun setUpMap() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }
        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location->
            if(location != null){
                lastLocation = location
                val currentLatLong = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                val userEmail = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.email.toString()
                val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                val lt = location.latitude
                val lg = location.longitude

                db.collection("users").get().addOnCompleteListener{
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        for(document in it.result!!){
                            if(document.data.getValue("email") == userEmail){
                                db.collection("users").document(document.id).update(
                                    mapOf(
                                        "latitude" to lt.toString(),
                                        "longitude" to lg.toString()
                                    )
                                )
                                //Log.d("TAG", "${document.data.getValue("online")}")
                            }
                            
                            //piece of code shown earlier
                            var ocherednyara: LatLng
                            if(document.data.getValue("online") as Boolean){
                                ocherednyara = LatLng((document.data.getValue("latitude") as Double), (document.data.getValue("longitude") as Double))
                                placeMarkerOnMap(ocherednyara)
                                //placeMarkerOnMap(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
                                //Log.d("TAG", "${document.data.getValue("online")} ${document.data.getValue("email")}")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLong)
                //placeMarkerOnMap(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLong, 15f))
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I enter the map activity, it crashes.
It works fine if I just use placeMarkerOnMap() of something else (e.g. 0.0, 0.0).
And even the Log writes values "online" and "email" (if the "ocherednyara" is hidden)

Please, help!

EDIT:
Error

```
2022-06-24 16:53:25.152 29971-29971/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.try5, PID: 29971
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
        at com.example.try5.MapActivity.setUpMap$lambda-1$lambda-0(MapActivity.kt:92)
        at com.example.try5.MapActivity.lambda$tjkw00NoTTc4ScPjZ_HOuv2ukvw(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.try5.-$$Lambda$MapActivity$tjkw00NoTTc4ScPjZ_HOuv2ukvw.onComplete(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

**92nd** code line is:

```
ocherednyara = LatLng((document.data.getValue("latitude") as Double), (document.data.getValue("longitude") as Double))
```

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsvMo.png)

Comment: Can you share your crash logs. Also make sure you call all these methods after onMapReadyCallback is called

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo, im not sure what stack trace is, im a newbee

Comment: @AlexMamo, I might have the same problem as this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54447296/i-need-to-add-markers-in-map-for-each-user-in-my-firebase-db . And I can see, that you tried to help him too, but the solution was not found anyway, so I had to post a question once again

Comment: Please show us the error.

Comment: @AlexMamo, i couldnt figure out how to do that, there's no such thing as (⠇). Added screenshot if that can help

Comment: Yes, screenshot, it's Firestore. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Indeed because of the following line of code:

```
ocherednyara = LatLng((document.data.getValue("latitude") as Double), (document.data.getValue("longitude") as Double))
```

And this is because you're trying to cast a String into a Double, which is actually not possible in Kotlin. What you should do instead is to get the value directly as a double:

```
                                                        //  
ocherednyara = LatLng(document.getString("latitude").toDouble(), document.getString("longitude").toDouble())
```

Comment: You're very welcome, Арсен. Have you solved the issue? Can I help you with other information?